# Right database for storing large amounts of entity relationship data

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, graph-databases, nosql

I'm trying to choose database which suits my use case.
Here is a simple EXAMPLE of what i'm trying to store in the database:

Lets say, we have 'users' and 'groups'. Each user can be part of any number of groups. There is also hierarchy in the groups ie.. each group can have multiple child groups.(and child groups can again have grandChildren and so on...)

Requirements:

- I will be adding MULTIPLE users to a parent group and they should be
  automatically added to all its child groups.. so, i just have to
  get all the child groups of the given group and add these users to
  every one of them. This operation SHOULD be atomic.
- I have multiple threads running in parallel updating the groups & adding users to them. I don't want any race conditions.

If we go With RDBMS approach, we will have A User table, A Group Table and relationship tables for user-group mapping and parentGroup-childGroup mapping.
I will be able to handle all the requirements using transactions/locks etc..

But,
 - the number of users are going be few million and each user on an
   average is a part of couple of hundred groups and height of group
   hierarchy tree is very less(<20), so the relationship tables are
   going to be really really big.
 - The Data which is stored in user table is unstructured.

From what i understand,

> NoSQL databases can handle this scale easily and are good with
>   unstructured data but they don't provide ACID features i need and SQL
>   databases are not good with handling large amounts of data.

I don't need any complex graph traversal queries expect the one i mentioned above.
I need only simple queries like getting all users in A group, getting all groups for A user etc.. but these queries SHOULD be fast.

So, What is the correct database for this use case??

Comment: You've put [tag:nosql] and [tag:relational-database]; and mentioned both as well. So which type are you asking about? Or is that the question?

Comment: @aneroid Yes, I'm trying to figure out what's the best database for this particular use case.